# How to determine the package for a specific perl module?

Tags: perl, package

Is there a way to determine the package for a specific perl module?
I'm currently looking for XML::Code...
And, to narrow down the possible answers: I don't want to use cpan.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By "cpan" you mean the tool, or CPAN itself? If so, why?

Comment: Same thing, isn't? The `package X;` declaration introduces a Perl module.

Comment: You should provide the OS you are looking for a package for this in.  If it is RedHat you should be able to do a yum search perl and then grep -i xml from it and see you options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean Debian package? Why not just search your repository for "XML::Code"? The following will usually give the answer, though.

1. Find the name of the distribution for the module by searching for the module on CPAN. In this case, it's [XML-Code](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Code).
2. Convert it to lowercase.
3. Perpend `lib`.
4. Append `-perl`.

So, `libxml-code-perl`.

Comment: I use `apt-file` for finding a perl modules in the Debian repository. `apt-file search XML/Code.pm`. Not all follow the same naming convention. Consider [libwww-perl](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/libwww-perl) for LWP::Useragent.

Comment: @jordanm, Like I said, the steps *usually* give the answer.

Comment: What makes you think that searching your repository for the name of the module isn't reliable?